# Configuring the Django development server output

Tags: django, manage.py

Is it possible to configure the output from the Django development server to show the IP address of the client making the request?

Comment: so an output line would look like this: 
[19/Sep/2010 11:49:46] 192.168.1.110 "GET /static/media/css/site.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0

Comment: instead of this:
[19/Sep/2010 11:49:46] "GET /static/media/css/site.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This in our list for "standard mods" to new Django releases. For Django 1.2.1, in django/core/servers/basehttp.py, line 614, change:

```
   msg = "[%s] %s\n" % (self.log_date_time_string(), format % args)
```

to

```
   msg = "[%s] %s %s\n" % (self.log_date_time_string(),
                       self.client_address[0], format % args)
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! I just added it to my list of Django standard mods too. Bummer we have to mod the code to get it, but as the Django devs say, they make frameworks, not servers.

Comment: Any other "standard mods" you'd like to share? I'd love to see your list!

Comment: I looked through what we have and put the ones most likely to be of use to you up on PasteBin. http://pastebin.com/bjpS1mgg. In addition to what I showed above, there is a new method, `cache.get_or_eval()` that simplifies checking/setting the cache, and another that fixes the template variable resolution method so that a simply value, e.g. {{something}}, will be called if it is, in fact, a callable(). We use curried functions wrapped around heavy-weight DB calls and pass those in the context. Both fixes are MonkeyPatches and will be frowned on by some. Meh.

Comment: Thank you for sharing those, Peter.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers I've had suggested to me:

1. Consider Gunicorn as a dev server: http://gunicorn.org/ (orginNell)
2. Consider using class inheritance on basehttp.py to create a new management command and avoid messing with the core code (orginNell)
3. Use a real server (Harro)
4. Write some middleware to log to a file (Harro)
5. Consider replacing the built-in server with django-devserver: http://github.com/dcramer/django-devserver (mikeshantz)
6. I like cherrypy with django: http://www.cherrypy.org/ (John M)
7. Cherokee is very good too: http://www.cherokee-project.com/ (John M)

Comment: Wow! I think I go more out of *your* answer than you probably did out of mine. Thanks!