# Add Username and Client IP Address in the Django manage.py runserver default output

Tags: django, python-3.x

Could anybody please help me, how to add Username and Clinet IP Address in the Django manage.py runserver default output.

currently I am seeing:
*[01/Jul/2019 11:34:27] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 237*

expected result:
*[pid: 10|app: 0|req: 1/2] 10.176.123.254 (Logged in username/email) {86 vars in 4942 bytes} [Mon Jul  1 06:08:37 2019] GET / => generated 291 bytes in 1160 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 7 headers in 250 bytes (1 switches on core 0)*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring the Django development server output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747062/configuring-the-django-development-server-output)